# Heroku domain issue

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare

Here is what I am using:
Heroku
Cloudflare
Domain.com

I have followed the instructions on cloudflare and so far I have my site showing up on the www url, but not on the root domain, I just get No such app. Here is what I have on my cloudflare panel:
[image: pic]
Based on what I read from the instructions here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-Cloudflare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS
This should be correct right? I get "no such app" whenever I try to view the root domain. I even got a "cname flattening" message which was mentioned in the instructions so I don't understand what's wrong. Also here is what I have for my Heroku app:
[image]

Comment: No, not correct. If you're CNAMEing to Heroku, you need to use the CNAME records they give you in the Heroku console in the custom domains section. They'd be different for www versus non-www.

Comment: @ceejayoz So I should add "skinterminal.com" as a domain as well and put it's DNS target into cloudflare? Edit: Also I am a noob when it comes to these kinds of things, appologies.

Comment: You need to add both `skinterminal.com` and `www.skinterminal.com` in Heroku's console, then add the corresponding CNAMEs in Cloudflare's DNS tool.

Comment: @ceejayoz alright, thanks!